# PHP&MySQL: issue using php for and mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop

I would calculate the total profit of a DataBase for each month using 12 different function [one for each month(yes its probably not a nice solution but I am learning step by step )]

This is the .php code (x12 times)

```
$January="SELECT JanuaryProfit()";     //Function
echo "<b>January Profit: E</b>";
$January = mysql_query($giugno,$conn)
          or die("Query failed: " . mysql_error($conn));
$num_rows=mysql_num_rows($January);

if (! $num_rows)
      echo "<p>0</p>";
else {
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($January)) {
            $price=$row[0];
            echo "$price";
      };
}
```

Function JanuaryProfit() is declared this way [MySQL]:

```
BEGIN
DECLARE PriceTOT FLOAT;
SELECT SUM(o.PrezzoTot) INTO PriceTOT
FROM orders o
WHERE o.Data BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2012-01-31';
RETURN PriceTOT;
END
```

And so I've declared singularly february,march,...,december.

I wouldn't paste 12 times the first code into the .php page.I've tried using a for cicle that use different function every time but i cannot figure how to solve this,correctly.Any suggest?

All I wanna do by now is changing the php part only,using a loop.

Comment: to clarify you have a procedure MarchProfit() and AprilProfit() etc in mysql?

Comment: yes,one function for each month

Comment: This is not just inefficient, it's *masochistic*. That's a new function every month, *every year*. Here is [the `LASTDAY()` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_last-day) which is probably your stumbling block.

Answer (score 1):

Oh my dear, sweet, flying spaghetti monster. Stop whatever you are doing, then burn it, and then use something like the below to avoid writing a function for every month of every year from the beginning of time until the end.

```
SELECT 
  YEAR(o.Data) as 'year',
  MONTH(o.Data) as 'month',
  SUM(o.PrezzoTot) as 'total'
FROM orders o
GROUP BY YEAR(o.Data), MONTH(o.Data)
```

I assume at some point you were having difficulty figuring out the last day of the month programmatically, so here's another link to [`LASTDAY()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_last-day) which is also the documentation page for all of the *massively useful* date functions.

---

### edit

```
define('masochism', TRUE);

$ohgodwhy = array('January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December');

$aaahhh = 'SELECT %sProfit()';

foreach( $ohgodwhy as $pleaseno ) {
    $itburns = sprintf($aaahhh, $pleaseno);
    $hidethebodies = mysql_query($itburns) or die("Couldn't hide the bodies because: " . mysql_error());
    // etc...
}
```

Comment: I agree with your solution but he did specify that he wanted to change ONLY the php file.  (I still +1 your answer)

Comment: @NappingRabbit I've updated my answer with some of the finest code ever written.